# Not able to load balance using hardcoded urls in spring cloud zuul

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I am testing spring zuul. I want to test round-robin requests forward using zuul routes. And **not** using eureka setup.

```
zuul.ignoredServices=*
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
server.port=9000
zuul.routes.trackingv1.path=/tracking/v1/**
zuul.routes.trackingv1.stripPrefix=false
zuul.routes.trackingv1.serviceId=trackingv1 
trackingv1.ribbon.listOfServers=http://localhost:8080/trackingv1,http://localhost:8081/trackingv1
```

But I am getting errors like `Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: trackingv1`

Any idea, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It's same old problem with using properties. (extra space in value part of key). I had extra space in 
`zuul.routes.trackingv1.serviceId=trackingv1<space>`

Now next problem is, from list of servers 
`trackingv1.ribbon.listOfServers=http://localhost:8080/trackingv1,http://localhost:8081/trackingv1`  it is picking online host:port portion. How to add contextPath "trackingv1" ?

Comment: ribbon only deals in hosts and ports